# How do I direct to a page in a different django folder from my views

Tags: python, django

I have two django folders, Accounts & Products.
I have the login html page in accounts and the productlist html page in products.
What I would like to do is if the login credentials are correct which is checked in the views file in Accounts, then it should be redirected to the productlist html in the Products folder.

How would I do this?

Comment: Redirecting is done by URLs, it makes absolutely no difference which app your destination is in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have Accounts and Products in different apps than there is on way
to specify for each app an urls.py and include them both in a root urls.py.
You can redirect easily to the url of Products than.

root urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
               url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),
              ]
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
                   url(r'^/$', view.Account.as_view(), name='account'),
              ]
```

products/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
                   url(r'^/$', view.Product.as_view(), name='product'),
              ]
```

in your view.py:

```
# ...
return HttpResponse('product')
```